# Flutter: Foreground notification is not working in firebase messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to show firebase notifications when the app is on foreground by using local notification but it is not working.

```
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin=new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  static StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _onMessageStreamController =
  StreamController.broadcast();
  static StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _streamController =
  StreamController.broadcast();
  static final Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> onFcmMessage =
      _streamController.stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var android=AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher.png');
    var ios=IOSInitializationSettings();
    var platform=new  InitializationSettings(android,ios);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(platform);

    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
  }
```

Here is the Firebase Code

```
 void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {

if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();

_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  print("FCM TOKEN--" + token);
});
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');
    showNotification(message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on resume $message');
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on launch $message');
  },
);


}
```

This is `showNotification` method

```
 void showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> msg) async{
    print(msg);
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'my_package', 'my_organization', 'notification_channel', importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High);
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform=new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,'My title', 'This is my custom Notification', platform,);
  }
```

and Firebase Response

> {notification: {title: Test Title, body: Test Notification Text}, data: {orderid: 2, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, order name: farhana}}

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @Farhana Are you able to fix this? i am also struggling with the same.

Comment: @Rocx yes, I resolved this issue

Comment: can you share some of the working code. Also wants to understand if i am on different page then do i get the onmessage notification? Or need to define it everywhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166526/flutter-fcm-fatal-failed-to-find-callback

Answer (score 8):

You can find the answer in FlutterFire documentation
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#messaging

You just add to your code the following line

```
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
```

Comment: Wow! THIS is the correct answer. THANK YOU. Note: Be sure to add this _after_ you app is initialized, ie after `await Firebase.initializeApp();`

Comment: Anytime bro @lenz

Answer (score 4):

There is an active issue logged on GitHub repository for the package regarding the same. Firebase messaging and local notifications won't work together on iOS since you can register only a single delegate for notifications.

Check out: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/111

There's also an active flutter issue for the same:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22099

Comment: I'm  working for Android, later on, I will work for ios and thanks for the info

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error or exception on Android? Or the notification won't show up?

Comment: i check on debug mode but no exception i was getting

Comment: I just tested the above code on Android and it is working for me. Can you check where exactly your code is failing? Is the `print(msg)` statement inside `showNotification()` getting executed?

Comment: actually, I was testing in oreo devic;

Comment: Is there a fix to this?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't. I bumped into this question too. After some research, I've found nothing helpful. So I decide to do it by myself using method channel.

Comment: ios rich image gif notifications also not possible! Did anyone find the solution for getting image notification on ios?

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:** 
See the Push Notification while application is in foreground.

**Solution:**
I was using firebase_message plugin and I was able to see the Push Notification while application is in foreground by making these few changes in my flutter project's iOS  AppDelegate.swift file in flutter project.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    // set the delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    // This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

**Note:**
This also works while using with flutter_local_notification plugin but with an issue that onSelectNotification is not working due to changes done above.

Comment: i can see the notification in foreground but my onMessage is not getting called. Any solution for this?

Comment: If you set the delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions then you will not be able to show a notification if you send notification object in the FCM payload and if you remove the user notification delegate method then show notification will not work

Answer (score 1):

For not receiving the notification in foreground make sure the android drawable file contains the launcher_icon or the icon which you have set in shownotification function.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get firebase notifications with flutter_local_notifications working on iOS in foreground. Background notifications worked fine. Problem was that firebase notification data is different on iOS. Notification data is not `["notification"]["title"]` as in android but `["aps"]["alert"]["title"]`.